# Do DBMSs store referencing attributes separately?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, foreign-key-relationship

Suppose I have the following relations (tables) :

`Student (id, name , family)
Course (id, title, unit, ref) 
Std-Course (std-id, course-id)` // std-id and course-id are foreign keys referencing to the Student and Course relations respectively.

Are std-id and course-id stored separately or they are just stored as pointers?
(specially in the `MySql` and `MS SQLSERVER`)

**Edit**: let me explain more this way :

If there is such a row `(123456, JOHN, SMITH)` in the `Student` table, and `(123456,db1)` in the `Std-Course` is `123456` stored twice or in the second table (as a foreign key) it's just a link?

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation:

> MySQL supports foreign keys, which let you cross-reference related
>   data across tables, and foreign key constraints, which help keep this
>   spread-out data consistent.

Meaning, we use child and as well parent to store data. The instruction of `foreign key ... references ...` would be stored in system table `table_constraints` to maintain the defined *relation* among the tables.

**Edit**:

> *If there is such a row (`123456`, `JOHN`, `SMITH`) in the Student table, and (`123456`,`db1`) in the `Std-Course`, is `123456` stored twice or in the second table (as a foreign key) it's just a link?*

It is stored twice. First in parent table and the second in child table.

References are not directly part of the table data. They are directives to the database system and are maintained in its own schema called `information_schema`.

The table `table_constraints` is part of this schema and holds information on all such constraints defined across various databases under the current instance of the `mysql`.

***Refer to***:

- [***MySQL: Foreign Key Constraints***](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: I'm quite a bit confused please look at the edit I've done to my question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I'm agree with you that constraints are not part of the data, however DBMS can take advantage of it, and as you know constraints and data are not too separate e.g. you should define an index on FKs in MySQL. BTW I can't find from your answer or the reference that MySql stores the data separately and doesn't store them as a link. I'll really appreciate if you provide a reference to this key part of my question.

Comment: See more under the same documentation. It says *Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing back to its parent.*

Comment: Yes, exactly. So is this behavior identical in the SQLSERVER?

Comment: See [SQL Server documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933117(v=sql.80).aspx). *A foreign key (FK) is a column or combination of columns used to establish and enforce a link between the data in two tables.* It clearly says key is a link between *data in two tables.*